# How to use scope identity with update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an `id` as primary key and I am setting that `id=scope identity()` in the insert procedure.

But I am unable to use that id with update procedure.

I want to write a procedure that will update the table with the id in the where condition, i.e.,

```
UPDATE TABLE [table name] 
SET col = @col, col2 = @col2 
WHERE id = @id
```

but my id is autogenerated i.e., `id int identity(1,1)`

How should I write update procedure?

Comment: If you want to update an entry in the database, it's a big advantage to know its id ;-). Or do you have another combination of criteria, that makes an item unique?

Comment: Google Store procedure with Out Parameter

Comment: "But I am unable to use that id with update procedure" why you are not able to use this ID in update procedure.. is it because you don't hold this value or due to some other reason?

Comment: i am using sql server  BEGIN
 SELECT @ItemGroup_Id = ItemGroup_Id
 FROM tbl_ItemGroup
 WHERE Group_Name=@Group_Name 
  UPDATE tbl_ItemGroup SET Group_Name=@Group_Name, Primary_Gr=@Primary_Gr,Under_Gr=@Under_Gr,Comments2=@Comments2
  WHERE ItemGroup_Id=@ItemGroup_Id

 END

Comment: this is my update procedure.now i am able to update.but i want update Group_Name also.but it is not updating

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `@id` as an in parameter to your stored procedure.
Your stored procedure should probably look something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <Procedure name>
(
   @id INT,
   @col1 <datatype>,
   @col1 <datatype>
)
AS
   UPDATE TABLE [table name] 
   SET col = @col, col2 = @col2 
   WHERE id = @id
```

Comment: i have id but is autogenerated.i.e i have set that id as identity(1,1).

Comment: @ShitalKashte You can only ser identity(1,1) in DDL

Comment: create table [tbl_name]( id int primary key not null identity(1,1)) i have created this in sql

Answer (score 0):

What I could understand is that you want to update the Table with the recent inserted row using @id = scope_identity(). Please see below the code to achieve this:

```
create proc abc
@col1 int,
@col2 int,
@id int
as
begin
set @id = ident_insert('TableA')
UPDATE TABLE [table name] 
SET col = @col, col2 = @col2 
WHERE id = @id
end
```

Let me know if this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with needing to insert new record then use the Scope_Identity to update an existing record with the new primary key from the insert.

My solution using  SQL Transaction

```
"DECLARE @TranName VARCHAR(24); " +
"SELECT @TranName = '" + LstranName + "';" +
"DECLARE @NewsupordID INT; " +
" BEGIN TRANSACTION[@TranName] " +
"BEGIN TRY " +
    "INSERT INTO SupplierOrder(SupplierKey, SupplierName, SupplierOrderDateOrdered, SupplierOrderStage, " +
         "SupplierOrderDateUpdated, SuppliersOrderNumber, SupplierOrderDateCreated, BackOrders, Notes) " +
     "VALUES('" + _newsuporder.SupplierKey + "','" + _newsuporder.SupplierName + "'," +
             "'" + _newsuporder.SupplierOrderDateOrdered + "','" + _newsuporder.SupplierOrderStage + "'," +
             "'" + _newsuporder.SupplierOrderDateUpdated + "','" + _newsuporder.SuppliersOrderNumber + "'," +
             "'" + _newsuporder.SupplierOrderDateCreated + "','" + _newsuporder.BackOrders + "'," +
             "'" + _newsuporder.Notes + "') SELECT @NewsupordID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()" +
     "UPDATE dbo.SupplierOrderItems " +
         "SET SupplierOrderItems.SupplierOrderKey = @NewsupordID " +
         "WHERE SupplierOrderItems.SupplierOrderItemKey = '" + Lssuporditemkey + "' " +
     "UPDATE dbo.OrderItems " +
         "SET OrderItems.SupplierKey = '" + Lssupplierkey + "', OrderItems.Modified = '" + Lsmodifieddate + "' " +
         "WHERE OrderItems.SupplierOrderItemKey =  '" + Lssuporditemkey + "' " +
    "COMMIT TRANSACTION[@TranName] " +
"END TRY " +
"BEGIN CATCH " +
"ROLLBACK TRANSACTION[@TranName] " +
"SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;" +
"END CATCH";
```

I then use

```
SqlCommand cmd_Command = new SqlCommand(sql_Add, cn_connection);
_iretrow = cmd_Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

to check if the sql was successful or rolled back.  I have earlier declared _iretrow as int = -1 .

LstranName is returned from a class I use to provide a unique tranaction which includes machine name, as ID for the SQL DB because multiple users access the DB.